# Join two group by commands into one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, message

I have a table

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|                         Message                                               |
|_______________________________________________________________________________|
| ID(INT) |  Text(TEXT) |read(TINYINT(0/1)) |deleted(TINYINT(0/1))|  User_id    |
| 1       | How Are You?|      0            |        0            |    6        |
| 2       | Fine        |      0            |        1            |    4        |
| 3       | Message 3   |      1            |        0            |    6        |
| 4       | Message 4   |      0            |        1            |    6        |
| 5       | Message 5   |      1            |        0            |    5        |
|_________|_____________|___________________|_____________________|_____________|
```

Now I want to select the  message where user_id=6 and also select the column count for read=0 and read=1 seperately.I know this can be done by group by command and iam currently doing it with two sql queries .May somebody join them in one

```
select message,count(*) from message where User_id=6 and read=0 group by id;//for unread message
select message,count(*) from message where User_id=6 and read=1 group by id;//for read message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you

```
select
  message,
  sum(read) as num_read,
  sum(case read when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_unread
from message
where user_id = 6
group by user_id
```

? You can drop either the where or the group by line, depending on your real need and SQL implementation.

Comment: Performance is hard to evaluate like this. All I can say is that the DMBS will likely only read your table once.

Answer (score 3):

Joining your two queries is quite easy, but I don't get what you really want.

```
SELECT `message`, count(*) AS `cnt` , `read`
FROM message 
WHERE `User_id`=6 
  AND `read` IN ( 0, 1 ) 
GROUP BY `id` , `read`;
```

Comment: See simon answer and tell me is here any drawbacks in his answer

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble Honestly his query at least makes sense on contrast to yours. So, if the result is, what you expect, I would suggest taking his query. I don't see any immediate drawbacks there. As he said, you should either drop the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` statement. Probably the later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select read,id,count(*) 
  from message 
 where user_id = 6 and read in (0,1) group by read,id
```